# Native multithreading - Java (how execute native methods properly)

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, java-native-interface

On the company where I work, I've been developing a wrapper for a motor in order to be able to operate it via a Java application. The Java application contains a GUI which can be used to manage the motor and its other functionalities. Here below are the codes for the motor.java class, the GUI.java and the dll code, respectively:

```
public class Motor {

    @NativeMethod
    private static native boolean nativeMove(double pos);
    @NativeMethod
    private static native boolean nativeBrake();


    public static synchronized boolean move(double pos) {
        if(Motor.nativeMove(pos))
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }

    public static synchronized boolean abortMotion() {
        if(Motor.nativeBrake())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

**GUI.java button's action listener definition:**

```
    btnMove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Thread t_move = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Motor.move();

                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                        }
                    });
                 }
              });
              t_move.start();
            }
        }
    );
    panel.add(btnMove);



    btnAbort.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Thread t_abort_motion = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Motor.abortMotion();

                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        }
                    });
                }   
            });
            t_abort_motion.start();

        }
    });
    panel.add(btnAbort);

}
```

**Motor wrapper (dll)**

```
bool MoveTo(double dTarget)
{
    BOOL flag;
    MoveCommand(dTarget);
    do
    {   
        Sleep(50);
        pIsMoving(&flag);
    }while(flag);
    if(syncPosition())
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}


JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_package_Motor_nativeMove(JNIEnv * env, jclass cls, jdouble pos) {

    if(MoveTo(pos))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}


JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_package_Motor_nativeBrake(JNIEnv * env, jclass cls) {

    if(brakeCommand())
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
```

As you can see, when any of the buttons inside the GUI class are pressed, they should generate a thread that should execute one native method (in this case, `nativeMove()` for one button and `nativeBrake()` for the other).

Here is my problem: whenever the motor is performing a movement, I simply cannnot execute the brake command. I believe that this is happening because the execution stays locked inside the while loop inside the `MoveTo(double pos)` function, even though I am using 2 different threads. I've tried to debug it to check if this was really the matter, but I had no success.
Also, since I am not that advanced in java multithreading and in native methods developing, I believe that I may be doing something wrong or forgetting to do something.

What could possibly be wrong here?

Comment: Your code is hard to read.  Having anonymous inner classes nested within other anonymous inner classes does not help.  The indentation looks wrong too.  I see you calling invokeLater() on a Runnable object whose run() method does nothing.  That's probably not what you intended.  It's harder to make that kind of mistake if your coding style is clean.

Comment: Consider using a thread pool (e.g., java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService) instead of creating a short-lived thread for each motor command.  Creating threads is expensive, and it could impact the responsiveness of your motor to button clicks.

Comment: Both motor.move() and motor.abortMotion() synchronize on the same global object (the Motor.class object).  That will prevent any thread from entering abortMotion() when some other thread is in motor.move().  Q: What is the use of "abortMotion()" if you don't allow it be called when the motor is moving?

Comment: You problem is `move` and `abortMotion` are synchronized. Which mean they can't executes simultaneously. Remove `synchronized` keyword. And make sure that you native methods are thread safe.

Comment: Your `Motor` class provides no means to specify _which_ motor.  I can't imagine a use-case for a project that can have only one motor.  (Controller for a one axis robot?)  And, how do you plan to do your testing when all of the methods are static?  In a product-quality system, I would expect Motor to be an interface, not a concrete class; and I would expect to be able to control different motors (both real, and simulations for testing) with different instances.  I know you're still working out low-level details, but it's never too early to get the architecture right.

Comment: Not the problem, but you don't need this `if (x()) return true; else return false;` stuff. You can replace that with `return x();`